# Is it possible to turn an Android PhoneGap and jQuery mobile application into an HTML5 cache manifest application?

Tags: android, html, flash, cordova, jquery-mobile

So I am working with PhoneGap and jQuery mobile to build my Android application, but within my application are flash swf movies which do not display I think this has something to do with PhoneGap. However I was wondering if I tried HTML5 manifest cache application then it might work,  its just that I am not entirely sure on how to go about it. Would I still be able to export it as an android application, how would I present it as an application in my device? I've looked at tutorials such as http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXZA9eS6nCw and HTML5 Application cache doctor but I am still finding it difficult to understand in terms of my application. Currently I am using xampp as my web server. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it but this is how I have done it so far and I placed them all within the server in htdocs.

Index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html lang="en" manifest="site.manifest">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HelloWorld App</title>
  <link href="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="see.css">

  </head> 
  <body>
   <!--background colour-->
  <img src="yaa/bluew.jpg" width="1048" height="800">

  <div data-role="page" id="page"data-role="page" data-theme="b">
  <!--header within the jQuery Mobile data colour theme page b for blue-->
  <div data-role="header">
          <h1><img src=yaa/header4.png alt="HelloWorld" width="529" height="178"200" />         </h1>
  </div>
      <div data-role="content"> 
        <ul data-role="listview">
          <p>
               <object width="710" height="493">
          <param name="movie" value="welcome.swf">
          <embed src="yaa/welcome.swf"
                 width="710" height="493"> </embed>
        </object>
          </p>
          <p> <button id="startButton" onclick ="location.href=    ('#page2');">Start</button> </p>
        </ul> 
      </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
          <h4>Welcome To HelloWorld</h4>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Site.Manifest 
    CACHE MANIFEST

```
# version 0.2

ind.html
jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css
jquery-1.6.4.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js
see.css


"site.manifest" [New] 8L, 74C written
preview.png
```

.htaccess

```
AddType text/cache-manifest manifest</p>

" .htaccess" [New] 1L, 37C written
```

This is just my PhoneGap java code

```
package com.helloapp.namespace.myhelloword;


import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;


public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");



    }



}
```

Please let me know if I am going in the right direction as I am not too sure of how to use HTML5 cache according to what I have presented. Plese let me know if I am to totally disregard java, thank you.